# How to change the style of the label of a checkbox if it's checked in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have the following controls:

```
            <span class="unCBox">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbNacional" CssClass="cbSecciones" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" AssociatedControlID="CheckBox1"></asp:Label>
            </span>
```

and my style is

```
.unCBox label{
margin: 10px;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid gray;
}
.unCBox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
border-color:blue;
background-color:black;
}
```

But it doesn't change when I check it, what am I missing?

Comment: Your code works for me in Chrome...

Comment: I don't know what's going on then..

Comment: Look [here](http://jsbin.com/redeqalogu/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Perhaps it gets overriden by some other css...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a solution using very little jQuery.Hope it helps you:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .checked {
            background-color: #ff6a00;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .unchecked {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #000000;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#CheckBox1").change(function () {
                var css = this.checked ? "checked" : "unchecked";
                $("#Label1").removeClass();
                $("#Label1").addClass(css);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <span class="unCBox">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbNacional" CssClass="cbSecciones" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" AssociatedControlID="CheckBox1"></asp:Label>
        </span>
    </form>
</body>
```